# Selenium is being detected even after modifying executable file

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bots

So currently I have changed the `$cdc_` string in selenium chrome driver and have added the following options as suggested by a website.

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--disable-blind-features=AutomationControlled')
option.add_argument("window-size=1280,800")
option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=option)
```

At this point I am not knowing what else to do. The functionality of the website allows my normal chrome browser to proceed past a certain point however when selenium is doing the same functions the website's server doesn't allow the bot to complete it's job. Any suggestions why the website could be detecting selenium?

Comment: Which websitie ?

Comment: [Website](https://www.nike.com/au/register) It when I selenium clicks the button 'JOIN US'

Comment: Whatberror are you getting

Comment: on my Linux Selenium works with this page without any changes `$cdc_` - it needs only sleep few second to wait for full page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open chrome using debbugger address as:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=1560 https://www.nike.com/au/register
```

Then you can connect to exisitng chrome browser :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('--disable-automation')
#options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")

options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1560")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)




driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[type="email"]').send_keys("someemail@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[type="password"]').send_keys("somepassword")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-componentname="firstName"]').send_keys("first")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-componentname="lastName"]').send_keys("last")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-componentname="dateOfBirth"]').send_keys("20/10/1980")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-componentname='gender']/li[1]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@value=\"JOIN US\"]").click()
```